# CheckboxList checkall should display conditionally?

Tags: php, yii

I have a checkbox list in my view inside gridview which works fine.

```
CHtml::checkBoxList('city', array(), $options, array('checkAll' =>'Select All' ));
```

It works fine but when there is no options in $options array checkAll checkbox still showing which is incorrect because we have no options. I want to show checkall only when I have non empty $options array.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
if($option){   
$array = array('checkAll' =>'Select All' ) 
}else{ 
 $array = array();
}


CHtml::checkBoxList('city', array(), $options, $array );
```